# Octopus Deploy variable substitution in appsetings.json

Tags: json, .net-core, octopus-deploy

How do I get a json variable replaced without it being placed in quotes ?
The `appsettings.json` contains a list of server names, `server:names` is an Octopus deploy variable that need to be replaced on deployment.

```
{
"server":
    {
        "names":  [ "#{server:names| JsonEscape}" ]
    }
}
```

Octopus variable is configured like this:
`server:names`        with value: `"server_x", "server_y"`

The result for names after replacement should be:

```
"names":  [ "server_x", "server_y" ]
```

but instead I'm getting the following result which makes the json file invalid:

```
"names":  [ ""server_x", "server_y"" ]
```

`Appsettings.json` needs the quotes but should be replaced by the Octopus Deploy. I can't use the `Json Configuration Variables` feature, it needs to substitute the variables.

Any ideas how I would go about this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use the Json Configuration Variables (now Structured configuration variables feature), I think the way to go is:

- change the variable value to `["server_x", "server_y"]`
- change the line in the JSON file to `"names": #{server:names}`

**Note**: JsonEscape is for escaping values that will go into JSON strings, not full JSON elements or nodes.

If you need to escape the server names, you may need to do that for the server names individually.

In your original example, you can remove the extra "s to get valid JSON. Or using my example above without JsonEscape produces the expected structure.

[image: Screenshot of script]

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, JSON only accepts member names as a string in double quotes.

Comment: Added more details on the answer - it's the extra "s in your original example file that's adding the "s around the list contents.

JsonEscape may or may not be necessary for what you're doing, but if you do use it, it will escape values that break JSON strings. It's not meant to escape whole JSON segments.

Comment: I can't remove the "s in the json file, because then VisualStudio would give me this warning "JSON property names should be strings, Identifier property names are not allowed in JSON"

Comment: My guess is for this to work you would have to ignore that warning as you're trying to substitute a JSON snippet into a file.

Comment: @ryan.rousseau Thank you, worked when i ignored that warnings in VS!